# Negative margin on different devices

Tags: android, density-independent-pixel

Source code can be found at : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts

I have following layout in my Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior=".behavior.QuickHideBottomBarBehavior">

        <com.sample.android.contact.widget.ListenableTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/triangle"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/triangle_shape"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see triangle ImageView includes : `android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"` and it works fine on my Google pixel2 420dpi device.

But in Galaxy nexus xhdpi It looks like this :[

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onNP1.png)

When I change marginBottom to -1.5dp it looks as expected.

What approach you suggest to resolve this issue?